# Use different css with multiple owl carousels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

How do you use different CSS on the controls of multiple owl carousels? The div with the controls is generated in JS, and the css applies to all owl carousels. How can I target the controls of a single carousel?

I want this code only applied on one owl carousel:

```css
.owl-theme .owl-controls{
    margin-top: -40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Wrap the owl carousal with a `<div id="something">` and use `#something .owl-theme .owl-controls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best solution is to wrap the carousel with a wrapper `div` with an `id` such as this one:

```
<div id="something">
  <div class="owl..... >
</div>
```

And use the `id` in the CSS like `#something .owl-theme .owl-controls` to target it:

```css
#something .owl-theme .owl-controls{
    margin-top: -40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```